# pkg-config doesn't see .pc file, even when containing folder is in PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: gentoo, pkg-config

I'm running gentoo linux, and I'm trying to get pkg-config to find ntk.pc (ntk being the library I'm trying to link to). Here are the premises:

Output of `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

Output of `locate ntk.pc`:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ntk.pc
```

Output of `pkg-config --modversion ntk`:

```
Package ntk was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `ntk.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'ntk' found
```

Output of `cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ntk.pc`:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: ntk
Description: Non ToolKit
Version: 1.3.0

Requires: cairo >= 1.9.0
Requires.private: x11 xft
Libs: -L${libdir} -lntk
Cflags: -I${includedir}/ntk -pthread -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

Any help would be awesome. If you need any more information, please leave a comment and I'll get it to you. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should ask this question on http://superuser.com/, you would be more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. It turns out that pkg-config didn't understand colon-delimiting like normal bash paths (/usr:/bin...etc), or my comp just needed a restart. Either way assigning $PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig works!